# Trivial Convergence lemma proof structure.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

I have been introduced to proofs and higher level mathematics and I am trying to understand the intuitive steps in proofs. One proof involves the proof of a certain lemma, which is quite obvious, but I am unsure about a specific step, and why it is necessary.

Lemma: Suppose $(a_n)$ converges to a limit, $\ell \gt 0$. Then there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(a_n) \gt 0$.

Proof:

If $(a_n)$ converges to $\ell$ then by definition of convergence of a sequence, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n- \ell| \lt \frac{\ell}{2} \quad \forall\, n \gt N$.

Then $ -\frac{\ell}{2} \lt a_n- \ell \lt \frac{\ell}{2}, \implies  \frac{\ell}{2} \lt a_n \lt \frac{3\ell}{2}$

So, $a_n \gt 0$, as $a_n \gt \frac{\ell}{2} \gt 0. \qquad \blacksquare$

Why suppose that $\epsilon =\frac{\ell}{2}$ in this case?

I know that it could have been any value, but for me, $\epsilon= \ell$ would have been the most obvious case.

I haven't wrote it exactly as the notes, but this is what I would write, if it was a question asked to me, so is there anything wrong with how I have structured this proof?

Comment: Well, you want a neighbourhood of $\ell$ away from zero. Such a neighbourhood has the form $(\ell - \epsilon, \ell + \epsilon)$, but with $\epsilon = \ell$ you get $(0, 2 \ell)$ which is NOT away from zero.

Comment: @Crostul sorry, I don't really understand what is meant by a 'neighbourhood of $\ell$ away from zero'. What does neighbourhood mean, in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The above comment essentially answers the question, but I think we can say something more, first of all note that the definition of limit you wrote down is **equivalent** to the one with non strict inequalities, namely for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n - l | \le \epsilon $ whenever $n \ge N$. If we choose $\epsilon = l$ we get $ 0 \le a_n \le 2l$ whenever $ n \ge N$, which of course does not mean that $a_n = 0$ for some $n$, but that technically it could be. So, since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, why not choose $\epsilon = \frac{l}{2}$ and get a "safer" inequality?